# plt.imshow() only shows black and white images

Tags: python, matplotlib, imshow

**I am trying to plot saliency maps. Original image (`png` file shape of (224,224,3)) is this:**

[image: original image]

**When I read the image and try to plot it by using `plt.imshow(_img)` it appears like this:**

[image]

**Therefore, my saliency map appears like this:**

[image]

**I tried `cmap` as `rgb`, `gray` and other functions. Nothing seems to be working.**

**Any ideas how to fix it?**

edit:

here is the code how I read the image:

```
_img = keras.preprocessing.image.load_img(img_,target_size=(512,512))
plt.imshow(_img)
```

`print(type(_img))`
`print(_img.format)`
`print(_img.mode)`
`print(_img.size)`

respectively gives:

`<class 'PIL.Image.Image'>`
`None`
`RGB`
`(512, 512)`

Comment: Possibly some issue regarding `int` vs. `float`, such that every pixel value `>= 1` will be clipped to white? Provide details (code) on how you read the image.

Comment: added the code.

Comment: Hm, downloading your PNG file and copy&pasting your code, gives the correct output. Can you post the versions of keras and matplotlib you are using?

Answer (score 0):

Try doing this before showing your image :

> tf.keras.preprocessing.image.img_to_array(_img, data_format=None,dtype=None)

Comment: I suggested you this because the keras command returns you a PIL image. And by doing the command above, it should have converted it to a numpy array, and then the plt.imshow() would work. Anyway, can u just try _img.show() then ?